# Parameterized type bounds

Tags: scala, types

I have the following trait (simplified example)

```scala
trait F[A, M[_] <: Option[A]] {

  def v: A

  def f: A => M[A]

}
```

I want to be able to create the following trait

```scala
trait G[A] extends F[A, Some]
```

But this gives the following error

`Error:(18, 20) type arguments [A,Some] do not conform to trait F's type parameter bounds [A,M[_] <: Option[A]]`

How can I bound the `M[_]` parameterized type ?

Edit :

A type `F[A, M[_] <: Option[_]]` will work. But I actually have another function in my trait

```scala
trait F[A, M[_] <: Option[_]] {

  def v: A

  def f: A => M[A]

  def f2: A => A = {
    (a: A) => f(a).get
  }

}
```

And in that case in `f2`, `get` doesn't return a value of type `A` even if `f` returns a `M[A]`

```
Error:(17, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : _$1
 required: A
    (a: A) => f(a).get
```

Comment: Can you just change the M[_] to M[A]?

Comment: Thanks Rich, changing `M[_]` to `M[A]` is actually working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fully constrain the type of `M` since it doesn't really need to take type parameters:

```
  trait F[A, M <: Option[A]] { // M no longer takes a type parameter
    def v: A
    def f: A => M
  }

  trait G[A] extends F[A, Some[A]] // Must specify M[A] since M doesn't take a type parameter
```

However you may want to provide some sort of mapping mechanism or something and go to some other type `M[B]` in which case a less constrained version would work better:

```
  trait F[A, M[_] <: Option[_]] { // M is no longer constrained to A
    def v: A
    def f: A => M[A] // M is manually constrained to A here
  }

  trait G[A] extends F[A, Some]
```

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately your `f2` function won't work. Even though we *know* that the types are correct, the compiler can't properly infer the type (limitations of Scala). You could add this function to `G[A]` and it will work as expected because `M[_]` has a concrete type with it now.

```
  trait G[A] extends F[A, Some]{
    def f3: A => A = a => f(a).get
  }
```

And as a side note, you should never use `Option.get`, it defeats the purpose of using an `Option`! `flatMap` it or something :)

Comment: Thanks Noah. I edited the question to match my use case. `F[A, M[_] <: Option[_]]` is what I want but I can't get the right type in my newly defined function.